# How to get [TAB] to work with arguments of aliases to autocomplete as can be done with the actual command

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

I have many aliases that I created in my `.bash_aliases` file, and they are very useful, so if I want all info on a package I do something like:

```
allinfo software-center
```

And that does the equivalent of:

```
apt-cache show software-center
```

As the alias is set as:

```
alias allinfo='apt-cache show'
```

But there is one disadvantage of this, I am currently unable to autocomplete with <kbd>TAB</kbd> when using `allinfo` instead of the actual command. So I was wondering if there was a way to overcome this disadvantage and make it so that doing `allinfo software-ce[TAB]` will work just the same as it does when you use it with the actual command, and not just make a large tab space?

I am using `gnome-terminal`.

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

**Package Information:**

```
gnome-terminal:
  Installed: 3.14.2-0ubuntu3
  Candidate: 3.14.2-0ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 3.14.2-0ubuntu3 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: This is a good question.  I love the idea behind it.  I have been looking all over, and I have found some close answers, but they fail when I try them.  If I come up with something, I will let you know.  =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question! If your `allinfo` command was the same as just `apt-cache`, (ie, without the `show`) then we could look at the completion for `apt-cache`, and apply that to your `allinfo` alias.

However, you want a subset of the `apt-cache` completion, so we have a little more work to do.

If we look in the completion definition for `apt-cache` - in `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/apt-cache`, we see the following is used for the `show` subcommand:

```
        COMPREPLY=( $( apt-cache --no-generate pkgnames "$cur" 2> /dev/null ) )
```

- this is just setting the `COMPREPLY` variable to the list of matching packages.

So, we can borrow this and write our own function, and bind it to your allinfo alias:

```
# define a function to print the possible completions for
# an allinfo invocation
_allinfo()
{
    _init_completion || return
    COMPREPLY=($(apt-cache --no-generate pkgnames "$cur" 2>/dev/null))
    return 0
}

# bind the above completion function to the 'allinfo' alias
complete -F _allinfo allinfo
```

If you add that fragement to your `.bashrc` file, you should get the completions working as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea for `bash`, but it works with `zsh` and some [plugins](https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen)

Install the z-shell with

```
sudo apt-get install zsh
```

and set the z-shell as your standard shell

```
sudo chsh "$USER" -s $(which zsh)
```

and start a new terminal to use the z-shell

Add [Antigen<sup>v1</sup>](https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen)

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/zsh-users/antigen.git
```

And configure

```
# path to antigen clone
source ~/antigen/antigen.zsh

# Load the oh-my-zsh's library.
antigen use oh-my-zsh

# Bundles from the default repo (robbyrussell's oh-my-zsh).
antigen bundle git
antigen bundle heroku
antigen bundle pip
antigen bundle lein
antigen bundle command-not-found
antigen bundle zsh-users/zsh-completions src

# Syntax highlighting bundle.
antigen bundle zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting

# Load the theme.
antigen theme robbyrussell
# antigen bundle nojhan/liquidprompt

# Tell antigen that you're done.
antigen apply
```

---

Some images (prompt is nojhan/liquidprompt)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah, that only works for me if I do exactly as you did, otherwise it just assumes that I am running `cd` and does the file path thing. How do I get it to read the `.bash_aliases` file?

Comment: I attempted to install those plugins, but I just got `antigen: command not found` on configuration.